# uninitialized constant Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, push-notification

I'm getting error "uninitialized constant Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE (NameError)" while executing command "rpush start".

I am trying to implement push notification using rpush in ruby on rails windows but not able to do that.
I'm pretty beginner in ruby on rails.
Please help.
mentioning my persistant.rb file

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'cgi' # for escaping
require 'connection_pool'

begin
  require 'net/http/pipeline'
rescue LoadError
end

autoload :OpenSSL, 'openssl'   


class Net::HTTP::Persistent

  ##
  # The beginning of Time

  EPOCH = Time.at 0 # :nodoc:

  ##
  # Is OpenSSL available?  This test works with autoload

  HAVE_OPENSSL = defined? OpenSSL::SSL # :nodoc:

  ##
  # The default connection pool size is 1/4 the allowed open files.

  DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE = Process.getrlimit(Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE).first / 4

  ##
  # The version of Net::HTTP::Persistent you are using

  VERSION = '3.0.0'

  ##
  # Exceptions rescued for automatic retry on ruby 2.0.0.  This overlaps with
  # the exception list for ruby 1.x.

  RETRIED_EXCEPTIONS = [ # :nodoc:
    (Net::ReadTimeout if Net.const_defined? :ReadTimeout),
    IOError,
    EOFError,
    Errno::ECONNRESET,
    Errno::ECONNABORTED,
    Errno::EPIPE,
    (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError if HAVE_OPENSSL),
    Timeout::Error,
  ].compact

  ##
  # Error class for errors raised by Net::HTTP::Persistent.  Various
  # SystemCallErrors are re-raised with a human-readable message under this
  # class.

  class Error < StandardError; end

  ##
  # Use this method to detect the idle timeout of the host at +uri+.  The
  # value returned can be used to configure #idle_timeout.  +max+ controls the
  # maximum idle timeout to detect.
  #
  # After
  #
  # Idle timeout detection is performed by creating a connection then
  # performing a HEAD request in a loop until the connection terminates
  # waiting one additional second per loop.
  #
  # NOTE:  This may not work on ruby > 1.9.

  def self.detect_idle_timeout uri, max = 10
    uri = URI uri unless URI::Generic === uri
    uri += '/'

    req = Net::HTTP::Head.new uri.request_uri

    http = new 'net-http-persistent detect_idle_timeout'

    http.connection_for uri do |connection|
      sleep_time = 0

      http = connection.http

      loop do
        response = http.request req

        $stderr.puts "HEAD #{uri} => #{response.code}" if $DEBUG

        unless Net::HTTPOK === response then
          raise Error, "bad response code #{response.code} detecting idle timeout"
        end

        break if sleep_time >= max

        sleep_time += 1

        $stderr.puts "sleeping #{sleep_time}" if $DEBUG
        sleep sleep_time
      end
    end
  rescue
    # ignore StandardErrors, we've probably found the idle timeout.
  ensure
    return sleep_time unless $!
  end

  ##
  # This client's OpenSSL::X509::Certificate

  attr_reader :certificate

  ##
  # For Net::HTTP parity

  alias cert certificate

  ##
  # An SSL certificate authority.  Setting this will set verify_mode to
  # VERIFY_PEER.

  attr_reader :ca_file

  ##
  # A directory of SSL certificates to be used as certificate authorities.
  # Setting this will set verify_mode to VERIFY_PEER.

  attr_reader :ca_path

  ##
  # An SSL certificate store.  Setting this will override the default
  # certificate store.  See verify_mode for more information.

  attr_reader :cert_store

  ##
  # The ciphers allowed for SSL connections

  attr_reader :ciphers

  ##
  # Sends debug_output to this IO via Net::HTTP#set_debug_output.
  #
  # Never use this method in production code, it causes a serious security
  # hole.

  attr_accessor :debug_output

  ##
  # Current connection generation

  attr_reader :generation # :nodoc:

  ##
  # Headers that are added to every request using Net::HTTP#add_field

  attr_reader :headers

  ##
  # Maps host:port to an HTTP version.  This allows us to enable version
  # specific features.

  attr_reader :http_versions

  ##
  # Maximum time an unused connection can remain idle before being
  # automatically closed.

  attr_accessor :idle_timeout

  ##
  # Maximum number of requests on a connection before it is considered expired
  # and automatically closed.

  attr_accessor :max_requests

  ##
  # The value sent in the Keep-Alive header.  Defaults to 30.  Not needed for
  # HTTP/1.1 servers.
  #
  # This may not work correctly for HTTP/1.0 servers
  #
  # This method may be removed in a future version as RFC 2616 does not
  # require this header.

  attr_accessor :keep_alive

  ##
  # A name for this connection.  Allows you to keep your connections apart
  # from everybody else's.

  attr_reader :name

  ##
  # Seconds to wait until a connection is opened.  See Net::HTTP#open_timeout

  attr_accessor :open_timeout

  ##
  # Headers that are added to every request using Net::HTTP#[]=

  attr_reader :override_headers

  ##
  # This client's SSL private key

  attr_reader :private_key

  ##
  # For Net::HTTP parity

  alias key private_key

  ##
  # The URL through which requests will be proxied

  attr_reader :proxy_uri

  ##
  # List of host suffixes which will not be proxied

  attr_reader :no_proxy

  ##
  # Test-only accessor for the connection pool

  attr_reader :pool # :nodoc:

  ##
  # Seconds to wait until reading one block.  See Net::HTTP#read_timeout

  attr_accessor :read_timeout

  ##
  # By default SSL sessions are reused to avoid extra SSL handshakes.  Set
  # this to false if you have problems communicating with an HTTPS server
  # like:
  #
  #   SSL_connect [...] read finished A: unexpected message (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

  attr_accessor :reuse_ssl_sessions

  ##
  # An array of options for Socket#setsockopt.
  #
  # By default the TCP_NODELAY option is set on sockets.
  #
  # To set additional options append them to this array:
  #
  #   http.socket_options << [Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, 1]

  attr_reader :socket_options

  ##
  # Current SSL connection generation

  attr_reader :ssl_generation # :nodoc:

  ##
  # SSL session lifetime

  attr_reader :ssl_timeout

  ##
  # SSL version to use.
  #
  # By default, the version will be negotiated automatically between client
  # and server.  Ruby 1.9 and newer only.

  attr_reader :ssl_version

  ##
  # Where this instance's last-use times live in the thread local variables

  attr_reader :timeout_key # :nodoc:

  ##
  # SSL verification callback.  Used when ca_file or ca_path is set.

  attr_reader :verify_callback

  ##
  # Sets the depth of SSL certificate verification

  attr_reader :verify_depth

  ##
  # HTTPS verify mode.  Defaults to OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER which verifies
  # the server certificate.
  #
  # If no ca_file, ca_path or cert_store is set the default system certificate
  # store is used.
  #
  # You can use +verify_mode+ to override any default values.

  attr_reader :verify_mode

  ##
  # Enable retries of non-idempotent requests that change data (e.g. POST
  # requests) when the server has disconnected.
  #
  # This will in the worst case lead to multiple requests with the same data,
  # but it may be useful for some applications.  Take care when enabling
  # this option to ensure it is safe to POST or perform other non-idempotent
  # requests to the server.

  attr_accessor :retry_change_requests

  ##
  # Creates a new Net::HTTP::Persistent.
  #
  # Set +name+ to keep your connections apart from everybody else's.  Not
  # required currently, but highly recommended.  Your library name should be
  # good enough.  This parameter will be required in a future version.
  #
  # +proxy+ may be set to a URI::HTTP or :ENV to pick up proxy options from
  # the environment.  See proxy_from_env for details.
  #
  # In order to use a URI for the proxy you may need to do some extra work
  # beyond URI parsing if the proxy requires a password:
  #
  #   proxy = URI 'http://proxy.example'
  #   proxy.user     = 'AzureDiamond'
  #   proxy.password = 'hunter2'
  #
  # Set +pool_size+ to limit the maximum number of connections allowed.
  # Defaults to 1/4 the number of allowed file handles.  You can have no more
  # than this many threads with active HTTP transactions.

  def initialize name: nil, proxy: nil, pool_size: DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE
    @name = name

    @debug_output     = nil
    @proxy_uri        = nil
    @no_proxy         = []
    @headers          = {}
    @override_headers = {}
    @http_versions    = {}
    @keep_alive       = 30
    @open_timeout     = nil
    @read_timeout     = nil
    @idle_timeout     = 5
    @max_requests     = nil
    @socket_options   = []
    @ssl_generation   = 0 # incremented when SSL session variables change

    @socket_options << [Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, 1] if
      Socket.const_defined? :TCP_NODELAY

    @pool = Net::HTTP::Persistent::Pool.new size: pool_size do |http_args|
      Net::HTTP::Persistent::Connection.new Net::HTTP, http_args, @ssl_generation
    end

    @certificate        = nil
    @ca_file            = nil
    @ca_path            = nil
    @ciphers            = nil
    @private_key        = nil
    @ssl_timeout        = nil
    @ssl_version        = nil
    @verify_callback    = nil
    @verify_depth       = nil
    @verify_mode        = nil
    @cert_store         = nil

    @generation         = 0 # incremented when proxy URI changes

    if HAVE_OPENSSL then
      @verify_mode        = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      @reuse_ssl_sessions = OpenSSL::SSL.const_defined? :Session
    end

    @retry_change_requests = false

    self.proxy = proxy if proxy
  end

  ##
  # Sets this client's OpenSSL::X509::Certificate

  def certificate= certificate
    @certificate = certificate

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  # For Net::HTTP parity
  alias cert= certificate=

  ##
  # Sets the SSL certificate authority file.

  def ca_file= file
    @ca_file = file

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # Sets the SSL certificate authority path.

  def ca_path= path
    @ca_path = path

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # Overrides the default SSL certificate store used for verifying
  # connections.

  def cert_store= store
    @cert_store = store

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # The ciphers allowed for SSL connections

  def ciphers= ciphers
    @ciphers = ciphers

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # Creates a new connection for +uri+

  def connection_for uri
    use_ssl = uri.scheme.downcase == 'https'

    net_http_args = [uri.host, uri.port]

    net_http_args.concat @proxy_args if
      @proxy_uri and not proxy_bypass? uri.host, uri.port

    connection = @pool.checkout net_http_args

    http = connection.http

    connection.ressl @ssl_generation if
      connection.ssl_generation != @ssl_generation

    if not http.started? then
      ssl   http if use_ssl
      start http
    elsif expired? connection then
      reset connection
    end

    http.read_timeout = @read_timeout if @read_timeout
    http.keep_alive_timeout = @idle_timeout if @idle_timeout

    return yield connection
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    address = http.proxy_address || http.address
    port    = http.proxy_port    || http.port

    raise Error, "connection refused: #{address}:#{port}"
  rescue Errno::EHOSTDOWN
    address = http.proxy_address || http.address
    port    = http.proxy_port    || http.port

    raise Error, "host down: #{address}:#{port}"
  ensure
    @pool.checkin net_http_args
  end

  ##
  # Returns an error message containing the number of requests performed on
  # this connection

  def error_message connection
    connection.requests -= 1 # fixup

    age = Time.now - connection.last_use

    "after #{connection.requests} requests on #{connection.http.object_id}, " \
      "last used #{age} seconds ago"
  end

  ##
  # URI::escape wrapper

  def escape str
    CGI.escape str if str
  end

  ##
  # URI::unescape wrapper

  def unescape str
    CGI.unescape str if str
  end


  ##
  # Returns true if the connection should be reset due to an idle timeout, or
  # maximum request count, false otherwise.

  def expired? connection
    return true  if     @max_requests && connection.requests >= @max_requests
    return false unless @idle_timeout
    return true  if     @idle_timeout.zero?

    Time.now - connection.last_use > @idle_timeout
  end

  ##
  # Starts the Net::HTTP +connection+

  def start http
    http.set_debug_output @debug_output if @debug_output
    http.open_timeout = @open_timeout if @open_timeout

    http.start

    socket = http.instance_variable_get :@socket

    if socket then # for fakeweb
      @socket_options.each do |option|
        socket.io.setsockopt(*option)
      end
    end
  end

  ##
  # Finishes the Net::HTTP +connection+

  def finish connection
    connection.finish

    connection.http.instance_variable_set :@ssl_session, nil unless
      @reuse_ssl_sessions
  end

  ##
  # Returns the HTTP protocol version for +uri+

  def http_version uri
    @http_versions["#{uri.host}:#{uri.port}"]
  end

  ##
  # Is +req+ idempotent according to RFC 2616?

  def idempotent? req
    case req
    when Net::HTTP::Delete, Net::HTTP::Get, Net::HTTP::Head,
         Net::HTTP::Options, Net::HTTP::Put, Net::HTTP::Trace then
      true
    end
  end

  ##
  # Is the request +req+ idempotent or is retry_change_requests allowed.

  def can_retry? req
    @retry_change_requests && !idempotent?(req)
  end

  ##
  # Adds "http://" to the String +uri+ if it is missing.

  def normalize_uri uri
    (uri =~ /^https?:/) ? uri : "http://#{uri}"
  end

  ##
  # Pipelines +requests+ to the HTTP server at +uri+ yielding responses if a
  # block is given.  Returns all responses recieved.
  #
  # See
  # Net::HTTP::Pipeline[http://docs.seattlerb.org/net-http-pipeline/Net/HTTP/Pipeline.html]
  # for further details.
  #
  # Only if <tt>net-http-pipeline</tt> was required before
  # <tt>net-http-persistent</tt> #pipeline will be present.

  def pipeline uri, requests, &block # :yields: responses
    connection_for uri do |connection|
      connection.http.pipeline requests, &block
    end
  end

  ##
  # Sets this client's SSL private key

  def private_key= key
    @private_key = key

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  # For Net::HTTP parity
  alias key= private_key=

  ##
  # Sets the proxy server.  The +proxy+ may be the URI of the proxy server,
  # the symbol +:ENV+ which will read the proxy from the environment or nil to
  # disable use of a proxy.  See #proxy_from_env for details on setting the
  # proxy from the environment.
  #
  # If the proxy URI is set after requests have been made, the next request
  # will shut-down and re-open all connections.
  #
  # The +no_proxy+ query parameter can be used to specify hosts which shouldn't
  # be reached via proxy; if set it should be a comma separated list of
  # hostname suffixes, optionally with +:port+ appended, for example
  # <tt>example.com,some.host:8080</tt>.

  def proxy= proxy
    @proxy_uri = case proxy
                 when :ENV      then proxy_from_env
                 when URI::HTTP then proxy
                 when nil       then # ignore
                 else raise ArgumentError, 'proxy must be :ENV or a URI::HTTP'
                 end

    @no_proxy.clear

    if @proxy_uri then
      @proxy_args = [
        @proxy_uri.host,
        @proxy_uri.port,
        unescape(@proxy_uri.user),
        unescape(@proxy_uri.password),
      ]

      @proxy_connection_id = [nil, *@proxy_args].join ':'

      if @proxy_uri.query then
        @no_proxy = CGI.parse(@proxy_uri.query)['no_proxy'].join(',').downcase.split(',').map { |x| x.strip }.reject { |x| x.empty? }
      end
    end

    reconnect
    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # Creates a URI for an HTTP proxy server from ENV variables.
  #
  # If +HTTP_PROXY+ is set a proxy will be returned.
  #
  # If +HTTP_PROXY_USER+ or +HTTP_PROXY_PASS+ are set the URI is given the
  # indicated user and password unless HTTP_PROXY contains either of these in
  # the URI.
  #
  # The +NO_PROXY+ ENV variable can be used to specify hosts which shouldn't
  # be reached via proxy; if set it should be a comma separated list of
  # hostname suffixes, optionally with +:port+ appended, for example
  # <tt>example.com,some.host:8080</tt>. When set to <tt>*</tt> no proxy will
  # be returned.
  #
  # For Windows users, lowercase ENV variables are preferred over uppercase ENV
  # variables.

  def proxy_from_env
    env_proxy = ENV['http_proxy'] || ENV['HTTP_PROXY']

    return nil if env_proxy.nil? or env_proxy.empty?

    uri = URI normalize_uri env_proxy

    env_no_proxy = ENV['no_proxy'] || ENV['NO_PROXY']

    # '*' is special case for always bypass
    return nil if env_no_proxy == '*'

    if env_no_proxy then
      uri.query = "no_proxy=#{escape(env_no_proxy)}"
    end

    unless uri.user or uri.password then
      uri.user     = escape ENV['http_proxy_user'] || ENV['HTTP_PROXY_USER']
      uri.password = escape ENV['http_proxy_pass'] || ENV['HTTP_PROXY_PASS']
    end

    uri
  end

  ##
  # Returns true when proxy should by bypassed for host.

  def proxy_bypass? host, port
    host = host.downcase
    host_port = [host, port].join ':'

    @no_proxy.each do |name|
      return true if host[-name.length, name.length] == name or
         host_port[-name.length, name.length] == name
    end

    false
  end

  ##
  # Forces reconnection of HTTP connections.

  def reconnect
    @generation += 1
  end

  ##
  # Forces reconnection of SSL connections.

  def reconnect_ssl
    @ssl_generation += 1
  end

  ##
  # Finishes then restarts the Net::HTTP +connection+

  def reset connection
    http = connection.http

    finish connection

    start http
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    e = Error.new "connection refused: #{http.address}:#{http.port}"
    e.set_backtrace $@
    raise e
  rescue Errno::EHOSTDOWN
    e = Error.new "host down: #{http.address}:#{http.port}"
    e.set_backtrace $@
    raise e
  end

  ##
  # Makes a request on +uri+.  If +req+ is nil a Net::HTTP::Get is performed
  # against +uri+.
  #
  # If a block is passed #request behaves like Net::HTTP#request (the body of
  # the response will not have been read).
  #
  # +req+ must be a Net::HTTPRequest subclass (see Net::HTTP for a list).
  #
  # If there is an error and the request is idempotent according to RFC 2616
  # it will be retried automatically.

  def request uri, req = nil, &block
    retried      = false
    bad_response = false

    uri      = URI uri
    req      = request_setup req || uri
    response = nil

    connection_for uri do |connection|
      http = connection.http

      begin
        connection.requests += 1

        response = http.request req, &block

        if req.connection_close? or
           (response.http_version <= '1.0' and
            not response.connection_keep_alive?) or
           response.connection_close? then
          finish connection
        end
      rescue Net::HTTPBadResponse => e
        message = error_message connection

        finish connection

        raise Error, "too many bad responses #{message}" if
        bad_response or not can_retry? req

        bad_response = true
        retry
      rescue *RETRIED_EXCEPTIONS => e
        request_failed e, req, connection if
          retried or not can_retry? req

        reset connection

        retried = true
        retry
      rescue Errno::EINVAL, Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e # not retried on ruby 2
        request_failed e, req, connection if retried or not can_retry? req

        reset connection

        retried = true
        retry
      rescue Exception => e
        finish connection

        raise
      ensure
        connection.last_use = Time.now
      end
    end

    @http_versions["#{uri.host}:#{uri.port}"] ||= response.http_version

    response
  end

  ##
  # Raises an Error for +exception+ which resulted from attempting the request
  # +req+ on the +connection+.
  #
  # Finishes the +connection+.

  def request_failed exception, req, connection # :nodoc:
    due_to = "(due to #{exception.message} - #{exception.class})"
    message = "too many connection resets #{due_to} #{error_message connection}"

    finish connection

    raise Error, message, exception.backtrace
  end

  ##
  # Creates a GET request if +req_or_uri+ is a URI and adds headers to the
  # request.
  #
  # Returns the request.

  def request_setup req_or_uri # :nodoc:
    req = if URI === req_or_uri then
            Net::HTTP::Get.new req_or_uri.request_uri
          else
            req_or_uri
          end

    @headers.each do |pair|
      req.add_field(*pair)
    end

    @override_headers.each do |name, value|
      req[name] = value
    end

    unless req['Connection'] then
      req.add_field 'Connection', 'keep-alive'
      req.add_field 'Keep-Alive', @keep_alive
    end

    req
  end

  ##
  # Shuts down all connections
  #
  # *NOTE*: Calling shutdown for can be dangerous!
  #
  # If any thread is still using a connection it may cause an error!  Call
  # #shutdown when you are completely done making requests!

  def shutdown
    @pool.available.shutdown do |http|
      http.finish
    end
  end

  ##
  # Enables SSL on +connection+

  def ssl connection
    connection.use_ssl = true

    connection.ciphers     = @ciphers     if @ciphers
    connection.ssl_timeout = @ssl_timeout if @ssl_timeout
    connection.ssl_version = @ssl_version if @ssl_version

    connection.verify_depth = @verify_depth
    connection.verify_mode  = @verify_mode

    if OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER == OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE and
       not Object.const_defined?(:I_KNOW_THAT_OPENSSL_VERIFY_PEER_EQUALS_VERIFY_NONE_IS_WRONG) then
      warn <<-WARNING
                             !!!SECURITY WARNING!!!

The SSL HTTP connection to:

  #{connection.address}:#{connection.port}

                           !!!MAY NOT BE VERIFIED!!!

On your platform your OpenSSL implementation is broken.

There is no difference between the values of VERIFY_NONE and VERIFY_PEER.

This means that attempting to verify the security of SSL connections may not
work.  This exposes you to man-in-the-middle exploits, snooping on the
contents of your connection and other dangers to the security of your data.

To disable this warning define the following constant at top-level in your
application:

  I_KNOW_THAT_OPENSSL_VERIFY_PEER_EQUALS_VERIFY_NONE_IS_WRONG = nil

      WARNING
    end

    connection.ca_file = @ca_file if @ca_file
    connection.ca_path = @ca_path if @ca_path

    if @ca_file or @ca_path then
      connection.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      connection.verify_callback = @verify_callback if @verify_callback
    end

    if @certificate and @private_key then
      connection.cert = @certificate
      connection.key  = @private_key
    end

    connection.cert_store = if @cert_store then
                              @cert_store
                            else
                              store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
                              store.set_default_paths
                              store
                            end
  end

  ##
  # SSL session lifetime

  def ssl_timeout= ssl_timeout
    @ssl_timeout = ssl_timeout

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # SSL version to use

  def ssl_version= ssl_version
    @ssl_version = ssl_version

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # Sets the depth of SSL certificate verification

  def verify_depth= verify_depth
    @verify_depth = verify_depth

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # Sets the HTTPS verify mode.  Defaults to OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER.
  #
  # Setting this to VERIFY_NONE is a VERY BAD IDEA and should NEVER be used.
  # Securely transfer the correct certificate and update the default
  # certificate store or set the ca file instead.

  def verify_mode= verify_mode
    @verify_mode = verify_mode

    reconnect_ssl
  end

  ##
  # SSL verification callback.

  def verify_callback= callback
    @verify_callback = callback

    reconnect_ssl
  end

end

    require 'net/http/persistent/connection'
    require 'net/http/persistent/pool'
```

Comment: Search for this file in your project and let me know
persistent.rb

Answer (score 1):

it happen, caused by net-http-persistent that uses internally referring to constants that do not exist in the Windows environment.

possible solutions:

1) add this line (perhaps other errors while following processing)

```
Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE = 7 if Gem.win_platform?
```

2) change your platform to *nix system:

```
irb(main):001:0> Gem.win_platform?
=> false
irb(main):002:0> Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE
=> 7
```

3) wait the merge of fix PR:

https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent/pull/90/files