# How can I get my Ruby gem 'Mechanize' to work?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize

I need to install the Ruby gem 'Mechanize' for a class that I am taking and do a project using it. I am using windows and I have tried installing versions 2.6.1 and 2.5.3 with the devkits from the website rubyinstaller.org. After installing these versions I have then done 'gem install mechanize' and the gem installs correctly. However when I try to use even " require 'mechanize' ", I get a sizable stacktrace and I cannot figure out what is wrong. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall everything multiple times.

The stacktrace:

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/net-http-persistent-3.0.0/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:205:in `<class:Persistent>': uninitialized constant Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/net-http-persistent-3.0.0/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:190:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.6/lib/mechanize.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is a known windows problem in one of this gem's dependencies, see: [uninitialized constant Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048855/uninitialized-constant-processrlimit-nofile-nameerror)

You might try the hack given there to put this line before your require

```
Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE = 7 if Gem.win_platform?
require 'mechanize'
```

You could also try running ruby inside some kind of virtualized environment if you are serious about becoming a ruby dev and you must use windows.  See [Developing in Ruby on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013270/developing-in-ruby-on-windows)

UPDATE: This is a known issue not for mechanize but one of its' dependencies see [this issue](https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent/issues/79) and the proposed workaround:

Locate the source path of the mechanize gem.  You should find it one of the paths shown in the results section from running

```
 gem env
 #look for a section that says:
 - GEM PATHS:
```

CD to the path from step 1, then `lib/net/http/persistent.rb` in your text editor: and modify this:

Find and remove this line:

```
DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE = Process.getrlimit(Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE).first / 4
```

Then add the following in it's place:

```
if Gem.win_platform? then 
  DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE = 256
else
  DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE = Process.getrlimit(Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE).first / 4
end
```

and save the file. Keep in mind if you use bundler and plan to run `bundle update` or `bundle upgrade` you will lose these changes. But this will hopefully be fixed in a some future release.  I have not tested this as I don't use windows, but you can try it.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Windows 10 v1803 x64, using rubyinstaller-devkit-2.5.3-1-x64.exe from https://rubyinstaller.org/ . Thanks!